# Need help writing code to brute-force a password that I partially forgot

Tags: passwords

I am trying to generate a password list to retrieve a password I have forgotten. The task is fairly simple, but I had no chance to find a solution on Google. So here is the problem:

I know the password consists of several words (without spaces), and I know the exact word order:

```
word1word2word3word4word5
```

Then there might be an exclamation mark at the end (!):

```
word1word2word3word4word5(AND/OR!)
```

Next thing, I know there are some underscores (_) in some places, but I don't know exactly where. So how could I generate a password list containing all the following possibilities:

```
word1(AND/OR_)word2(AND/OR_)word3(AND/OR_)word4(AND/OR_)word5(AND/OR !)
```

I am pretty sure programs such as crunch, hashcat or john the ripper could easily solve this problem, but all variations I have tried have failed, for instance on crunch, one can use specific patterns with a -t argument, but it proved impossible (at least for me) to use a pattern which includes variations (AND/OR underscore...)

Comment: this is a programming question, not a security question

Comment: could also be a software recommendation request for free password cracking tools with list-making helpers. Also off-topic for infosec.SE. @alladin, you might look at some of the Related links on the side though, some of them might be helpful.

Comment: thanks, then what would be the best place to post this question?

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I have already read these links, found nothing useful for my specific case. Frustrating, because I know the task is pretty simple (generate a list of passwords with only a few minor differences), but I lack the programming knowledge to solve it on my own...

Comment: Ok, if you're looking for help writing a program to do this, then I'll vote to move this to Stack Overflow. (it may not be in the right place immediately, but it'll get you closer).

Comment: Quick Answer: Use a program called 'HashCat' to generate password lists based on rules.  Or you may find another software called 'Crunch' easier to use and create rule sets for.  Again, wrong place to ask this question =)

Comment: @MikeOunsworth In it's current form, this question will not do well on Stack Overflow. To be welcome on  Stack Overflow, the OP should show what they've tried write themselves. A [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: All right, as long as I can get some help :) I have tried crunch and hashcat, but couldn't find an example for this case. Although I am sure that they are able to solve this problem. PS: I am sorry for the noobish level, I have a very low programming level. Just trying to get some help from more experienced users who dealt with a similar situation.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] the question, and show what you've tried. A show of effort is usually appreciated on Stack Exchange. Good luck!

Comment: @S.L.Barth Oops. That shows how often I go to StackOverflow. Maybe from now on I should refrain from voting to migrate there...

Comment: I have slightly edited the question to include a mention of what I have tried with crunch... I also did some testing with john the ripper, but cannot remember exactly what, just that nothing worked. Searches on Google were not helpful

Comment: Given your explanation, there are only 32 possibilities. Why on earth do you need John the Ripper? Just type the thing and see if it works.

Comment: @alladin Ok, there's a show of effort in the question. I'm voting this up as an encouragement. Normally, Stack Exchange sites want more detail - like showing the exact inputs and outputs. Apologies if I sound pedantic. I want to encourage you, but also to warn you that these sites are very critical. Anyway, good luck, hope you'll find a solution!

Comment: @JohnWu yes I know there aren't a lot of possibilities, but I thought that would be a good opportunity to learn how to do it properly. Always nice to learn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to re-invent the wheel.

[CUPP](https://github.com/Mebus/cupp) is your best bet. It's a python script that takes average data about someone, keywords you think are relevant, and even uses LEET mode to turn E's in 3's, etc. This will spit out a password list for you in seconds and you can then run it with your cracking tool of choice.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, will give it a try. Would you have an example on how to use it in this specific case?

Comment: The examples are so subjective, just run
     python cupp.py -i   to get the interactive version and it will ask you questions that you need to answer.